# posh-git doesn't show branch in package manager console

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, visual-studio-2012, nuget, posh-git

I installed posh-git for Windows PowerShell and it works great in the shell. However, it is supposed to work in the package manager console as well. It does work but it doesn't show the current branch like the normal powershell window does.

I followed [this tutorial](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DesktopDev/MSTech/posh-git-in-the-nuget) and everything went fine except for my package manager console doesn't look like his with the branch name.

[image]

All you can see is `PM>` in the VS 2012 package manager console.

[image]

But it works fine in the powershell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nuget has a separate profile (~\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\NuGet_profile.ps1), so it's not picking up the posh-git installed in your default profile.

The easiest way to get posh-git working is to run `install.ps1` from the Package Manager Console. Or if you always want your profiles to match, you can load your default profile in the Nuget one:

```
$PROFILEDIR = (Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition -Parent)
Push-Location $PROFILEDIR

. .\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1

Pop-Location
```

(Edited to include switching to profile directory; capturing location in `$PROFILEDIR` is optional, but I find it handy.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had to slightly tweak the line you suggest to add to `NuGet_profile.ps1` in `. $HOME\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`. Without this change the default profile was not loaded -- indeed, if I run the command you propose in the Package Manager Console, Powershell complained that it was unable to find the script.

Comment: Ah yes, the profile is executed from the context of your default working directory. See my edit for how I usually get around this.

Comment: Thanks for following up and improving your answer -- this way I've learned something new in Powershell.