# Unable to execute git push from Package Manager Console with GitHub for Windows installed

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, git, github, nuget

I've set up Visual Studio 2010 in order to use Git from the Package Manager Console, more precisely:

- I've installed msysgit (adding Git executables under `%PATH%`);
- I've installed Posh Git and I've enabled it using the instructions given in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454399/posh-git-doesnt-show-branch-in-package-manager-console/12487340).

I've also installed GitHub for Windows for easy access to repositories hosted on GitHub.

From the Package Manager Console I am able to do all the operation locally, but when I want to push to a GitHub repository the prompt seems "blocked", I cannot kill `git` using the Stop button and I'm forced to close Visual Studio and to push from the Git Shell provided with GitHub for Windows.

Using Process Explorer I can see that `git` spawn the GitHub for Windows program to do the authentication and from there it doesn't seem to advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've resolved this issue by installing the [Windows Credentials Store for Git](http://gitcredentialstore.codeplex.com/) (also suggested in the [TFS blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/03/08/use-the-git-command-prompt-to-supplement-visual-studio.aspx)), so that it handles the authentication instead of GitHub for Windows.

Now I can do `git push` from Package Manager Console -- the credentials store asks for credentials the first time and then pushes correctly to GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

If your repository is hosted on Team Foundation Service (not on GitHub), then besides installing the Windows Credentials Store for Git (as answered by edymtt), you must enable basic authentication before you can use the command prompt to perform Git tasks. You can set this up from your User Profile in TFS. http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd286572(v=vs.120).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Install git for Windows.

It includes the Git Credential Manager, it adds everything needed to PATHS and so on =)

https://git-scm.com/download/win